# Odd behavior with a PHP POST

Tags: php

So I'm seeing an odd behavior and I asked over on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/527195/odd-httpd-behavior-while-uploading-a-file/527196?noredirect=1#527196) but it looks to be a code issue. The thing is this code works fine when I test locally with MAMP, once I put it on HostGator I get this oddness.

So the process is

1. Upload file;
2. Check the state of things;
3. Unzip the file;
4. Read in a data file;
5. Copy and thumbnail images;
6. dump data into database.

I know 1 to 5 happen as I can see the thumbnails. The oddness is I get an error from step 2 saying the file didn't upload. So it looks like the whole process is started over with "blank" POST data.

So, step 1 is this bit of code. It's called when my form is posted:

```
function action_upload() {
    $ownerName = $this->request->post('ownerName', '');
    $ownerEmail = $this->request->post('ownerEmail', '');
    $ownerPhone = $this->request->post('ownerPhone', '');
    $username = $this->request->post('username', '');
    $password = $this->request->post('password', '');
    $treeName = $this->request->post('treeName', '');

    $error = $this->util->process_datafile($ownerName, $ownerEmail, $ownerPhone, $username, $password, false, $treeName);

    if ($error != "") {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'error' => $error,
        ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'gotoURL' => "/" . $treeName,
        ));
    }
    exit;
}
```

The action reads in some form fields and calls a function `process_datafile` that, well, processes the uploaded file. Below is that function, the error I'm recieving is from the 9th line, "No tree name provided". But I know it at some point gets past that error.

```
public function process_datafile($ownerName, $ownerEmail, $ownerPhone, $username, $password, $update, $treeName) {

    // Make sure we have a tree name
    if ($treeName != "") {
        $this->scriptPath = dirname(__FILE__);
        $this->treePath = dirname(dirname($this->scriptPath)) . "/assets/trees/" . $treeName . "/";
        $this->tempFilePath = dirname(dirname($this->scriptPath)) . "/assets/temp/" . $this->guid() . "/";
    } else {
        return "No tree name provided";
    }

    // Check to make sure the tree is in the expect condition
    $treeExists = false;
    if (file_exists($this->treePath)) {
        $treeExists = true;
    }
    if ($treeExists && !$update) {
        return "Tree name already exists " . $this->treePath;
    } else if (!$treeExists && $update) {
        return "Tree does not exists";
    }

    // Make sure there are no upload errors
    if ($_FILES['treeFile']['error'] == '1' || $_FILES['treeFile']['error'] == '2') {
        return "File size to large, try to upload your tree without media.";
    } else if ($_FILES['treeFile']['error'] != '0') {
        return "File upload error: " . $_FILES['treeFile']['error'];
    }

    // Move the uploaded file
    if (!file_exists($this->tempFilePath)) {
        mkdir($this->tempFilePath, 0700, true);
    }
    $name = $_FILES["treeFile"]["name"];
    $tempfile = $this->tempFilePath . $name;
    copy($_FILES['treeFile']['tmp_name'], $tempfile);


    // Make sure it is something we can deal with
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $fileparts = explode(";", finfo_file($finfo, $tempfile));
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $filetype = $fileparts[0];
    $valid = "text/plain,image/png";
    if (($filetype != "text/plain" && $filetype != "application/zip") || ($ext != "ged" && $ext != "zip")) {
        return "Only gedcom (.ged) or archive (.zip) files may be uploaded.";
    }

    $gedfile = $tempfile;
    $archive_tmp = "";
    if ($filetype == "application/zip" && $ext == "zip") {
        $archive_tmp = $this->tempFilePath . "archive/";
        if (!file_exists($archive_tmp)) {
            mkdir($archive_tmp, 0700, true);
        }

        // Extract the archive
        $zip = new \ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open($tempfile);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($archive_tmp);
            $zip->close();
        } else {
            $this->delTree($archive_tmp);
            return "Error processing archive";
        }

        // Find the gedcom
        $found = false;
        $it = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($archive_tmp);
        foreach(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
        {
            $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if (strtolower($file_ext) == "ged") {
                $gedfile = $file;
                $found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!$found) {
            $this->delTree($archive_tmp);
            return "Could not find gedcom (.ged) file in archive.";
        }
    }

    // Make the tree folder if needed
    if (!file_exists($this->treePath)) {
        mkdir($this->treePath, 0700, true);
    }
        $this->mediaPath = $this->treePath . "media/";
    $this->delTree($this->mediaPath);
    if (!file_exists($this->mediaPath)) {
        mkdir($this->mediaPath, 0700, true);
    }
    if (file_exists($this->treePath . "tree.ged")) {
        unlink($this->treePath . "tree.ged");
    }
    copy($gedfile, $this->treePath . "tree.ged");


    // Deal with the database
    if (!$this->create_database($ownerName, $ownerEmail, $ownerPhone, $username, $password, $update)) {
        return "Could not open database";
    }

    // Process the gedcom
    $this->process_gedcom($this->mediaPath, $archive_tmp);

    // Remove the temp folder
    $this->delTree($this->tempFilePath);

    return "";
}
```

I know at some point it gets into the `process_gedcom` as that where the thumbnailing takes place... I also know it never gets to `foreach ($ged->people as $person)` as there are no entries in the database.

```
private function process_gedcom($mediaPath, $archivePath) {
    // Insert statements
    $personInsert = "INSERT INTO people   (id, gender, first, last, middle, title, suffix) VALUES (:id, :gender, :first, :last, :middle, :title, :suffix)";
    $nameInsert   = "INSERT INTO names    (personID, `type`, first, last) VALUES (:id, :type, :first, :last)";
    $familyInsert = "INSERT INTO families (id, personAID, personBID) VALUES (:id, :personAID, :personBID)";
    $childInsert  = "INSERT INTO children (familyID, `type`, personID) VALUES (:familyID, :type, :personID)";
    $eventInsert  = "INSERT INTO events   (personID, familyID, `type`, date, place, description) VALUES (:personID, :familyID, :type, :date, :place, :description)";
    $factInsert   = "INSERT INTO facts    (personID, name, value) VALUES (:personID, :name, :value)";
    $mediaInsert  = "INSERT INTO media    (id, file, `type`, title) VALUES (:id, :file, :type, :title)";
    $peopleMediaInsert = "INSERT INTO people_media (mediaID, personID) VALUES (:mediaID, :personID)";
    $familyMediaInsert = "INSERT INTO family_media (mediaID, familyID) VALUES (:mediaID, :familyID)";


    // Load in the gedcom file
    $ged = new \App\Gedcom();
    $ged->import($this->treePath . "tree.ged", array($this, 'log'));


    // Add objects to the database
    foreach ($ged->objects as $obj) {
        $file = $this->findFile($obj->getFilename(), $archivePath);
        if ($file !== false) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $fileparts = explode(";", finfo_file($finfo, $file));
            $filetype = $fileparts[0];
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $hash = md5_file($file);
            copy($file, $mediaPath . $hash . "." . $ext);
            $this->makeThumb($mediaPath . $hash . "." . $ext, 200, 200, "thumb");
            $this->makeThumb($mediaPath . $hash . "." . $ext, 1024, 768, "resized");
            $this->database($mediaInsert, array(':id'    => $obj->getId(),
                                                ':file'  => $hash . "." . $ext,
                                                ':type'  => $filetype,
                                                ':title' => $obj->getTitle()));
        }
    }

    // Add people to the databsse
    foreach ($ged->people as $person) {
        $this->database($personInsert, array(':id'     => $person->getId(),
                                             ':gender' => $person->getGender(),
                                             ':first'  => $person->getFirstName(),
                                             ':last'   => $person->getLastName(),
                                             ':middle' => $person->getMiddleName(),
                                             ':title'  => $person->getTitleName(),
                                             ':suffix' => $person->getSuffixName()));
```

More data inserts...

What would cause things to restart as it looks like its calling `process_datafile` twice, once with valid inputs, the second time everything is '' blanks?

Comment: Just echo a stack trace at line 9, it'll tell you where the call is coming from

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct in your case, but for once I had a slide show plugin with jQuery which it was loading images on-demand. Whenever it was trying to load something, my whole routing system was triggering some of my functions, because my system architecture was corrupt. My guess may would be that there is something like a script is triggering your whole process again and it's not sending anything because it is on the fly. I tracked this with `Net` layer in Firebug.